# My Interrail global pass shows 3 inbound/outbound days in total in the app. How is it permitted to use the third day?

Tags: trains, interrail

I have an Interrail global pass in mobile format, shown in the Rail Planner app.

One point that surprised me is that there are 3 outbound/inbound days in total although classic rules tells that there are only two trips allowed in the country of residence in total.

I enquired the Interrail support directly and they told me that the residents of my country are allowed a third outbound or inbound day, with no additional explanation on eventual limitations, and just to enjoy being able to take advantage of that new condition.

This is confusing, as a popup in the app tells that the extra day may be present in case it takes a long time to travel out of / back into my country of residence.

The pass has a long duration. I have a plan to split my travel using this pass in two sessions with returning home in-between. For the additional inbound and outbound trips not covered by the pass, I would simply buy point-to-point tickets from my home to the border station.

In this situation, can I use the third day as an actual additional outbound travel day, saving the cost of one domestic ticket? The answer given by Interrail support would let me think that this is permitted, but I am still in doubt about it. I really want to avoid being considered in fraud in the middle of my travel.

Comment: Probably that it's a legal requirement, that your country happens to be so massive (like Germany or Poland), that it can take a long time to arrive home (which could span of different days)

Comment: Here's an "official" explanation in case it's useful, although it doesn't say more than the answer below https://eurail.zendesk.com/hc/en-001/articles/11170800337821-Extra-outbound-inbound-journeys-visible-on-the-Rail-Planner-app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing has changed in Interrail's terms and conditions about the number of trips. You are still only allowed one outbound and one inbound journey in your country of residence.

What Interrail has recently changed is for residents of some countries to allow to use more than one calendar day for each of the outbound or inbound trips, as was the previous restriction. The reason is simply that some countries are so large and/or have so slow trains, that it for some pass holders may be impossible to do the outbound/inbound journeys in one day.

I find the three days on your pass a little bit odd though. I know that pass holders with residence in Norway now get four days, which makes more sense. If you can't make the outbound trip in one day, it is also unlikely that you can make the inbound trip in one day, which will only be solved if you have a total allowance of four days. With three days, you would still not be able to make either the outbound or the inbound trip.

Comment: Makes sense if you use an international sleeper train to go back home, crossing the border in the middle of the night, and need an onward connection in your country of residence on the following day. Because crossing the border on the sleeper train is tricky to do using the app without having to consume the day of departure as an inbound one. The outbound travel would require just one day in the country of residence, while the inbound one would require two (day of boarding the sleeper + next one for domestic connections)

Comment: @DavGin Just as it would make sense to have two days for the outbound journey if you start the trip with a domestic or very late departing night train and need to continue on a new train the second day, still being in your country of residence. It is not difficult to construct scenarios, even in smaller countries, where it would make sense to be able to use more than one day for either of the outbound/inbound journeys. Therefore, a three days allowance is a bit odd, since it only solves the problem in one direction.

Comment: The three days are applied to residents in Switzerland. All sleeper trains leave before midnight and end up in a different country. Unless you need to connect to smaller mountain lines to reach home, one day is largely enough for travel from any station to the border.